How to provide versions of a package depending on Fastify 4 and on Fastify 5 without duplicating code?
I'm implementing a package which has to start a Fastify server to respond to some requests. Most of its users will be using Node v20+, and so can use Fastify 5, but I don't want to make it a hard requirement. Instead I want to provide both versions, especially since I'm lucky enough not to need any code differences, just dependencies.
My initial idea was to use Yarn workspaces to have two packages in the repo, the main one with "fastify": "^4.28.1 || ^5.1.0" in dependencies, and the second one depending on the main package and on "fastify": "^4.28.1". But this won't work: when someone depends on this package, "fastify": "^4.28.1 || ^5.1.0" will be in transitive dependencies and get resolved to Fastify 5. Neither will putting Fastify 4 in resolutions of the second package instead of dependencies.
Maintaining two release branches with dependencies on Fastify 4 and 5 would work, but I'd prefer to avoid it.
My current plan is just to check Node and Fastify versions on start-up and fail with a message to set resolutions to Fastify 4 if they don't match. Any better alternatives?
Of course, if I could say in package.json "use Fastify 5 for Node 20+ and Fastify 4 before that" it would solve the problem, but I don't believe that to be possible.
